# Please help! Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in blog code, no idea how to fix it!

Tags: php, errors

This is currently the code:

```
<?php
//* Start the engine
include_once( get_template_directory() . '/lib/init.php' );


//* Enqueue scripts and styles
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ohwild_scripts_styles' );
function ohwild_scripts_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'ohwild-responsive-menu', esc_url( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . '/js/responsive-menu.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'dashicons' );

}

//* Register responsive menu script
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ohwild_enqueue_scripts' );
function ohwild_enqueue_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'ohwild-responsive-menu', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/responsive-menu.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true ); 

}


//* Child theme (do not remove)
define( 'CHILD_THEME_NAME', 'cecilla' );
define( 'CHILD_THEME_URL', 'http://cecilla.ohwild.com' );
define( 'CHILD_THEME_VERSION', '1.0' );


//* Add HTML5 markup structure
add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'search-form', 'comment-form', 'comment-list', 'gallery', 'caption' ) );

//* Move header & footer outside wrap
remove_action( 'genesis_footer', 'genesis_do_footer' ); 
add_action( 'genesis_after', 'genesis_do_footer' );

remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_do_header' );
add_action( 'genesis_before', 'genesis_do_header' );

//* Add viewport meta tag for mobile browsers
add_theme_support( 'genesis-responsive-viewport' );

//* Add support for custom header
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', array(
    'width'           => 750,
    'height'          => 110,
    'flex-width'      => false,
    'flex-height'     => false,
    'header-selector' => '.site-title a',
    'header-text'     => false,
) );

//* Add new image sizes
add_image_size( 'featured', 230, 230, TRUE );

//* Remove the secondary sidebar
unregister_sidebar( 'sidebar-alt' );

//* Unregister secondary navigation menu
add_theme_support( 'genesis-menus', array( 'primary' => __( 'Primary Navigation Menu', 'genesis' ) ) );

//* Remove site layouts
genesis_unregister_layout( 'content-sidebar-sidebar' );
genesis_unregister_layout( 'sidebar-sidebar-content' );
genesis_unregister_layout( 'sidebar-content-sidebar' );
genesis_unregister_layout( 'content-sidebar' );

//* force sidebar/content layout
add_filter( 'genesis_pre_get_option_site_layout', 'child_do_layout' );
function child_do_layout( $opt ) {
    { 
        $opt = 'sidebar-content'; // You can change this to any Genesis layout
        return $opt;
    }
}

//* Remove the header right widget area
unregister_sidebar( 'header-right' );

//* Customize the entry meta in the entry header
add_filter( 'genesis_post_info', 'ohwild_entry_meta_header' );
function ohwild_entry_meta_header( $post_info ) {

    $post_info = '[post_date format="F j, Y"] [post_categories]';
    return $post_info;


//* Move leave a comment link to bottom of post
add_filter( 'genesis_post_meta', 'ohwild_entry_meta_footer' );
function ohwild_entry_meta_footer( $post_meta ) {

    $post_meta = '[post_comments zero="0" one="1" more="%"]';
    return $post_meta;

}

//* Remove comment form allowed tags
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'ohwild_remove_comment_form_allowed_tags' );
function ohwild_remove_comment_form_allowed_tags( $defaults ) {

    $defaults['comment_field'] = '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . _x( 'Comment', 'noun', 'ohwild' ) . '</label> <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>';
    $defaults['comment_notes_after'] = '';  

    return $defaults;

}

//* Modify the size of the Gravatar in the author box
add_filter( 'genesis_author_box_gravatar_size', 'ohwild_author_box_gravatar' );
function ohwild_author_box_gravatar( $size ) {

    return 175;

}

//* Modify the size of the Gravatar in the entry comments
add_filter( 'genesis_comment_list_args', 'ohwild_comments_gravatar' );
function ohwild_comments_gravatar( $args ) {

    $args['avatar_size'] = 110;
    return $args;
}

//* Customize search form input box text
add_filter( 'genesis_search_text', 'sp_search_text' );
function sp_search_text( $text ) {
    return esc_attr( 'search + hit enter' );
}

//* Remove footer widgets
remove_theme_support( 'genesis-footer-widgets', 3 );

//* Add support for 1 footer widget
add_theme_support( 'genesis-footer-widgets', 1 );



//* Hook featured posts
add_action( 'genesis_after_content_sidebar_wrap', 'add_genesis_widget_area' );
function add_genesis_widget_area() {
                genesis_widget_area( 'after-content-widget', array(
        'before' => '<div class="after-content-widget widget-area">',
        'after'  => '</div>',
    ) );

}

genesis_register_sidebar( array(
    'id' => 'after-content-widget',
    'name' => __( 'Featured Posts Widget', 'ohwild' ),
    'description' => __( 'This area will display after the content and above the footer. Display your popular posts here.', 'ohwild' ),
) );


// Display featured image on post and page
add_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'featured_post_image', 8 );
function featured_post_image() {
  if ( !is_singular( array( 'post', 'page' ) ))  return;
    the_post_thumbnail('large');
}

// Add Read More Link to Excerpts
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'ohwild_get_read_more_link');
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'ohwild_get_read_more_link' );
function ohwild_get_read_more_link() {
   return ' <div class="read-more"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">read more</a></div>';
}


/**
* Remove Image Alignment from Featured Image
*
*/
function be_remove_image_alignment( $attributes ) {
$attributes['class'] = str_replace( 'alignleft', 'aligncenter', $attributes['class'] );
return $attributes;
}
add_filter( 'genesis_attr_entry-image', 'be_remove_image_alignment' );


//* Customize footer
remove_action( 'genesis_footer', 'genesis_do_footer' );
add_action( 'genesis_footer', 'indiebirdie_custom_footer' );
function indiebirdie_custom_footer() {
echo '<div class="creds"><p>';
echo 'All Rights Reserved &copy; ';
echo date('Y');
echo ' / Site Designed by <a href="http://indiebirdie.com">Indie Birdie</a>';
echo '</p></div>';
}
```

Does anybody know how to fix it? I would be incredibly grateful!

Answer (score 1):

`ohwild_entry_meta_header()` is missing the closing `}`.